# Why is screen.width equal to window.innerWidth even though window.devicePixelRatio is not 1 when i use mobile?

Tags: javascript, web, mobile, browser

For example, we know that Iphone 5's resolution ratio in x is 640px,and the devicePixelRatio of it is 2. So I guess the screen.width is 640px and window.innerWidth is 320px (devicePixel/devicePixelRatio). But I found that the window.innerWidth is equal to screen.width,which is 320px.

If I test it a browser on PC, I can always get that screen.width/window.innerWidth === devicePixelRatio

Where is the problem?

BTW, I'm using chrome.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/. It's good because it provides many different ways to get the viewport size.

Comment: I've editet your question for spelling, punctuation and capitalization. Please try your best to use proper English in future communications on StackOverflow. We try to maintain a professional level here, and you will have a hard time attracting answers if your question does not parse easily.

Comment: i'm sorry for that and thank you!